# duplicate column during pivot table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table like

select * from myTable

```
ID  Type    Prop1    Prop2    Prop3    Prop4    Prop5
--  ------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------
1   Hot     10       9        23       32       4
1   Cold    2        24       53       34       5
2   Hot     11       9        23       32       4
2   Cold    22       1        53       30       11
```

I want to pivot my table like that

select * from myPivotTable

```
ID  HotProp1 HotProp2 HotProp3 HotProp4 HotProp5 ColdProp1 ColdProp2 ColdProp3 ColdProp4 ColdProp5 
--  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
1   10       9        23       32       4        2          24       53         34       5
2   11       9        23       32       4        22         1        53         30       11
```

How can I convert myTable to myPivotTable using **pivot** function in oracle sql?

Comment: I have two types in Type column. I am stucking on that duplicate new columns using together propX columns and Type records. I couldn't configure it yet in sql. @RichBenner

Comment: I jumped straight into pivoting(using `pivot/unpivot` clause), but of course, simple conditional aggregation(see @Gordon Linoff answer) is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Oracle version 11g and up you can simply "re-pivot" it(You have already pivoted data) - unpivot it first and then pivot again:

```
with t1(id1, type1, Prop1, Prop2, Prop3, Prop4, Prop5) as(
  select 1,   'Hot' ,  10 ,  9 , 23,32 , 4 from dual union all
  select 1,   'Cold',  2  ,  24, 53,34 , 5  from dual union all
  select 2,   'Hot' ,  11 ,  9 , 23,32 , 4  from dual union all
  select 2,   'Cold',  22 ,  1 , 53,30 , 11 from dual 
  )
 select *
   from( select *
           from t1
        unpivot (
          val for col in (prop1, prop2, prop3, prop4, prop5)
        )
   )
   pivot(
     max(val) for (col, type1) in (('PROP1', 'Hot') as HotProp1, 
                                   ('PROP2', 'Hot') as HotProp2, 
                                   ('PROP3', 'Hot') as HotProp3,
                                   ('PROP4', 'Hot') as HotProp4,
                                   ('PROP5', 'Hot') as HotProp5,
                                   ('PROP1', 'Cold') as ColdProp1,
                                   ('PROP2', 'Cold') as ColdProp2,
                                   ('PROP3', 'Cold') as ColdProp3,
                                   ('PROP4', 'Cold') as ColdProp4,
                                   ('PROP5', 'Cold') as ColdProp5)
   )
```

Result:

```
      ID1   HOTPROP1   HOTPROP2   HOTPROP3   HOTPROP4   HOTPROP5  COLDPROP1  COLDPROP2  COLDPROP3  COLDPROP4  COLDPROP5
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         10          9         23         32          4          2         24         53         34          5
         2         11          9         23         32          4         22          1         53         30         11
```

[Here is the demo](http://rextester.com/YONP58264)

Comment: Is here any way for skipping unfivot step? @Nicholas Krasnov

Comment: @neverwinter As I already told you in the comment to your question, yes, of course there is a much more efficient way that avoids using `unpivot, pivot` clauses altogether - simple conditional aggregation (see Gordon Linoff answer).

Answer (score 2):

I think conditional aggregation is a much simpler query than a complex pivot:

```
select id,
       sum(case when type = 'Hot' then Prop1 end) as Hot_Prop1,
       sum(case when type = 'Hot' then Prop2 end) as Hot_Prop2,
       sum(case when type = 'Hot' then Prop3 end) as Hot_Prop3,
       sum(case when type = 'Hot' then Prop4 end) as Hot_Prop4,
       sum(case when type = 'Hot' then Prop5 end) as Hot_Prop5,
       sum(case when type = 'Cold' then Prop1 end) as Cold_Prop1,
       sum(case when type = 'Cold' then Prop2 end) as Cold_Prop2,
       sum(case when type = 'Cold' then Prop3 end) as Cold_Prop3,
       sum(case when type = 'Cold' then Prop4 end) as Cold_Prop4,
       sum(case when type = 'Cold' then Prop5 end) as Cold_Prop5
from myPivotTable
group by id;
```